# Is my 1/4 sheet palm sander going to die?

Tags: sander

I was using the 1/4 sheet sander the other day when the motor was getting funny. This started about 4 months ago and got worse. What happens is the motor does not start up to full speed. After some time running it would kick up and run like it is supposed to, but this did not last because it went back to a slow speed. This is a fairly old sander, but am not sure for this was handed down to me from great grandma. It has not been sitting outside or anything so I do not think the dry, cold weather had anything with it. But maybe in the summer because humidity is about 75% around here.

So with that said, do I need to get rid of this tool before something dangerous happens (like would it start on fire?) If it is not the motor, how else can I fix it?

Update: Well my sander died already. I could not get to the brushes since they where inside the sander. But since it was dead I looked. The brushes were fine but they snapped out of place it appeared. Otherwise I couldn't see a problem with it. But it is not worth trying to fix this one. The brand is Skil. Model I do not know, the sticker wasn't there. I have another old sander so it should be good for a while. When it's dead, I will move to a Ryobi cordless sander.

Comment: This is fairly difficult to answer as we don't know what type of sander (brand, model, etc) it is, but there are some "generic" steps you could try. Have you tried just taking it apart and looking at it? If it truly is an older sander I can only imagine that it's not all that complicated inside so if you were to do this you could possibly see the issue and then just fix it. It could just be something as simple as dust got stuck up inside the motor or the lubrication got dried up. Just try cleaning it and adding some lubrication of some sort.

Comment: Check the brushes; blow dust out with compressed air. If that doesn't change things, get back to us.

Comment: I will take a look at brushes and stuff and get back, along with some other stuff. Did not think of that (sometimes I am a rock). I will also, in my update, include the sander brand and model. Its not that old but from what I know, reasonably old.